# LogRecord.getSourceMethodName() returning lambda$0

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java.util.logging

When I call `java.util.logging.Logger.log(Level, String)` from a lambda, the `java.util.logging.LogRecord.getSourceMethodName()` method returns lambda$0 at my `Formatter`.

For instance:

```
public void doStuff() {
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    names.add("John");
    names.add("Paul");
    names.add("George");
    names.add("Ringo");

    names.forEach((beatle) -> Logger.getLogger("myLog").log(Level.SEVERE, beatle));
}
```

How can I get the method name (doStuff) instead 'lambda$0'?

PS.: I wouldn't like to get it from StackTrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation of the Logger class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html):

> For the methods that do not take an explicit source name and method name, the Logging framework will make a "best effort" to determine which class and method called into the logging method. However, it is important to realize that this automatically inferred information may only be approximate (or may even be quite wrong!). Virtual machines are allowed to do extensive optimizations when JITing and may entirely remove stack frames, making it impossible to reliably locate the calling class and method.

Therefore, the way to solve your problem is to specify the class name and method name:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("myLog");
names.forEach(beatle -> logger.log(Level.SEVERE,
    getClass().getName(), "doStuff", beatle));
```

Comment: Instead of `getClass().getName()` it’s better to use `SuroundingClass.class.getName()` as the actual type of `this` as returned by `getClass()` is not necessarily the class containing the actual `doStuff()` implementation. Further, the lambda expression doesn’t need to capture `this` then.

Comment: @Holger I agree, and personally I always do it that way.  But the OP didn't include a class name, and I wanted to keep the answer simple.

Comment: @VGR I've also thought about this workaround, but it could be a problem in case of renaming the method. It would be necessary to remember to update the String too.

Comment: @hbelmiro: I suggest keeping the renaming of `public` methods to a minimum…